What do you think partner of a partner in a Polyamorous relationship should be called?
So technically if they themselves aren't romantically (and/or sexually) involved with each other, then they can't be addressed as husband/wife /boyfriend/girlfriend.
They can't be called Brother-husbands or Sister-wives since these terms indicate Polyandry and Polygyny relationships (respectively).
Is there a single word that could be used to describe them?

They are either lovers or they're not. The question asks what relationship it is when you don't have one.

There's no term for this. Polyamorous relationships aren't common enough that we have special terms for them. So you'd use a phrase like "My partner's lover."

And English in general has far fewer kinship terms than many other languages. We use the same word "brother-in-law" for the brother of our spouse and the husband of our sibling.

As a business can have two or more partners, why can't a relationship?

While it is quite possible that there is no established term for this kind of a relationship (and that the only way to respond to the question is by inventing one, which would be off-topic), the question should not be dismissed: people who live in such relationships do need a term with this meaning and it is possible that it is emerging. The question should be reopened to give chance to somebody familiar with the current polyamorous practices to post an informed answer to it.

Contrary to what Barmar says, people in polyamorous relationships have an endless series of terms for all kinds of things, it's just that nobody outside a very small community uses or knows these words. So maybe there's a word but I guarantee it's one only 0.01% of people or less will know.

@jsw29 I agree.

@Stuart F thanks for the link.
